# Spark split comma separated row array into first value and the rest

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a dataset:

```
val raw_data = sc.parallelize(Array(
    "Batch1, i, 10, j, 20",
    "Batch2, i, 20, k, 30, m,50",
    "Batch3, i, 30, n, 20, j, 30"
))
```

I want to split out the first entry or each row into it's column before I process the data further. I tried:

```
raw_data.map(x => x.split(",")).map(x=>(x(0), x))
```

but then I get:

```
"Batch1", "Batch1, i, 10, j, 20",
"Batch2", "Batch2, i, 20, k, 30, m,50",
"Batch3", "Batch3, i, 30, n, 20, j, 30"
```

when I work in python I can do indexing like:

```
x(1:)
```

to select everything after the first value. is there something like that in scala?

ie

```
raw_data.map(x => x.split(",")).map(x=>(x(0), x(1:)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `head` and `tail`:

```
raw_data.map(x => x.split(", ")).map(x=>(x.head, x.tail))
```

Also you might want to split on `", "` rather than `","` if you don't want unnecessary spaces in your result.